# HStore Index for sorting by an arbitrary key

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I'm running queries that rely on sorting and comparison of the value for an arbitrary key inside an HStore, e.g:

```
SELECT * FROM hstest WHERE h->'key1' >= 'a';
SELECT * FROM hstest ORDER BY h->'key1';
```

where `h` is an HStore field. These queries work, but I'm wondering what's the best way to index the field for these type of searches.

I know I can do something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX hstest_index_h ON hstest USING BTREE ((h->'key1'));
```

But is there a way to create an index that works for an arbitrary key on the HStore (i.e. `key1` is determined by the end-user)?

Comment: Have you looked at Gist and Gin indexes if you want to be able to determine if the key exists using the ?| operator.

Comment: Yes, I know I can add a GiST / GIN index for checking if a key is present, but are those helpful for sorting the value at a key?